# Is there a way to breakdown user access within a Jira project by component

Tags: jira

I was asked to separate access to a particular Jira project by component.  e.g. user "a" can see issues created for component "a", but not component "b".  conversely, user "b" can see issues created for component "b", but not component "a".

I know that I can limit access to a particular project to one or more users, but I was unaware of a way to filter access to one or more users by component within a Jira project.

Is there any way to limit access to one or more people to a subset (less than all components) of a project?

I did a search for a Jira plugin that might offer this functionality, but did not find what I was looking for.

N/A

N/A

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible by using a component (I don't think so), but there is an alternative approach which might be sufficient as well:

You can adjust the **Browse Projects** permission like this:

[image: You can grant permission to a **group custom field value** and then you could choose a custom group field (create one if not available) which will be evaluated on each issue.]

You can grant permission to a **group custom field value**. Then you could choose a custom group field (create one if not available) which will be evaluated on each issue. Then, if you create an issue and add a group to this custom field in that issue, only users from that group have access to view the issue. Take care that you remove the **any logged in user** setting for "Browse Projects", otherwise the group custom field does not have any effect. There is also a [KB article here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/managing-project-permissions-938847145.html) in Jira's documentation.

Comment: s.hesse, thank you for your solution.  I'm going to try that, then respond back.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is what are you trying to do? Why do you want to restrict who can view issues?

Jira has Issue Security Schemes that can do this based on setting the security level according to the component, or other fields. I'd use a custom create post function

But what happens when the component is changed? Now you have to restrict editing too.

Comment: The request was to selectively allow certain people to see some tickets in a project but not others.  Specifically, this is for a recruitment project, so for instance, development hiring managers/interviewers should be able to see developer applicants, but should not have access to recruitment tickets of non-development applicants.

Comment: That sounds like issue security schemes to me. Check out the Set Security permission team. And remember that Jira admins can see everything in Jira in the end